# Is there a way to temporarily disable Duplicate entry in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I keep on getting the below error message when I try to enter some important records I accentually deleted.
    Duplicate entry 'EMIR2023 ' for key 'flightNo'

Is there a way in the phpMyAdmin environment I can disable the UNIQUE KEY then activate it when I am done with inserting the records?

Find below the structure of my table, I hope it helps

```
--
-- Table structure for table `flightSched`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `flightSched` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `timePeriod` time DEFAULT '00:00:00',
  `depOrArriv` varchar(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `flightNo` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  `airline` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dest` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `origin` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  `depature` time DEFAULT '00:00:00',
  `don` set('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday') DEFAULT NULL,
  `arrivalTime` datetime DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `arrivalTimeSec` varchar(28) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `image_type` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image` blob NOT NULL,
  `image_size` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `flightNo` (`flightNo`),
  UNIQUE KEY `arrivalTime_2` (`arrivalTime`),
  KEY `arrivalTime` (`arrivalTime`),
  KEY `arrivalTime_3` (`arrivalTime`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=537 ;
```

Looking forward to your reply :-)

Comment: [`INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: Yes - on the Structure page, just remove the unique index then re-add it. It's not phpMyAdmin imposing the limit, it's the underlying database itself.

Comment: @LuckySpoon Thanks! your advice worked like a charm. After I have finished adding my records how do I add it without tampering with the records in the table and without having to re-create the table?

Comment: If you have a duplicate entry EMIR2023, you won't be able to put back the unique key index on this column.

Comment: @SirBT To re-add the UNIQUE index, on the right side of the structure page for each column there is a icon which is a black U - click this on the unique column and it will attempt to add it. As Marc said though, if your data is not unique this will throw errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try  unique_checks

```
SET unique_checks=0;
... import operation ...
SET unique_checks=1;
```

[check reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/converting-tables-to-innodb.html)

Comment: Cant really get this to work, could you kindly clarify in code?